# Bigquery java api failing to load data - "file does not exist on cloud"

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Loading data into Bigquery using the Java API's is failing saying the file does not exist on cloud. However the Google Cloud Storage location is correct and works fine when using the browser to load the data.

This used to work before the Google Cloud Storage JSON API v1 release. I'm not sure if this is related.

Any idea if something changed recently?

Comment: Please include a job id from a failing job and we can help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it and turns out it was the api issue:

This is what was failing:

```
cloudstorage.objects().get(bucket, uri).execute();
```

Here's the error messaage:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Version v1beta2 of this API is no longer available. Please try again using JSON API v1. To request temporary reinstatement for your project, please visit https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1isIxBZg3rsQbDN_TOalZaz1WT_ebJchsrlv-Qr_r9mY/viewform?entry.244568692=866447901597&entry.176324201=v1beta2&entry.1071661541-Qr_r9mY/prefill",
    "reason" : "turnedDown",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/migrate"
  } ],
  "message" : "Version v1beta2 of this API is no longer available. Please try again using JSON API v1. To request temporary reinstatement for your project, please visit https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1isIxBZg3rsQbDN_TOalZaz1WT_ebJchsrlv-Qr_r9mY/viewform?entry.244568692=866447901597&entry.176324201=v1beta2&entry.1071661541-Qr_r9mY/prefill"
}
```

Comment: Hi 

you correct this problem? i have exactly the same error message